# Normalization method for Multi Layer Perceptron

Tags: neural-network, normalization

I am implementing a classification using MultiLayer Perceptrons.

I need to do normalization of input data. I was wondering which is a better method for MultiLayer Perceptron approach. The input feature have different ranges as per below

feature1 - (0-1)
feature2 - (1-100)
feature2 - (1-100000)
.
.
.

1. Max-Min Normalization: Range(0,1) Activation Function - Sigmoid

normalized_data = (data-min)/(max-min)

1. standard deviation normalization  : Range (-1,1) - Not Sure Sigmoid will be good choice.. Hyperbolic tangent??

normalized_data = data-mean/sd

Thanks,
Atish

Answer (score 0):

If you want to normalize every row of your training dataset, the appropriate method is `mapminmax` method from Neural Network toolbox.

If you tend to normalize based on each column (feature), there are too many ways. If your dataset consists of different boundary, it is better to normalize between `[-1 1]`, otherwise `[0 1]` is appropriate.

The normalization method between `[-1 1]` can be coded:

```
function xNorm = Normalization(x,MinX,MaxX)
% x is data, MinX is minimum values in each column and MaxX is maximum values in each column

xNorm = (x - MinX) / (MaxX - MinX) * 2 - 1;

end
```

`xNorm` is normalized input data between -1 and 1.

Another solution is `normc` function, which normalize the columns of a matrix.

Comment: `Gaussian` function is another most appropriate normalization method which try to takes into consideration `mean` and `Std.` of the distributed data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we normalize between [-1 1].. then should I change my activation function from sigmoid to hyperbolic??

Comment: The `hyperbolic tangent function` provides similar scaling to the `sigmoid activation function`; however, the `hyperbolic tangent activation function` has a range of `[-1 1]`. So, it is better to apply hyperbolic. Another idea is that, since `hyperbolic tangent activation function` has a derivative characteristic, it can also produce output in range of `[0 1]`.

Comment: Do we need to normalize the output also ?? I have a 5 class classification problem. They take values as following.
[1 0 0 0 0] or [0 0 1 0 0]

Comment: @alex, you can normalize them, if there is a range of value. but for your bit range value, it is not mandatory. because normalization try to range data between 0 an 1 and your output is in this range. Also, in most training, without normalization of the output, weights and biases can be adjusted correctly.